# Why ASP.NET Core Identity cookie authentication doesn't work?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, asp.net-web-api, cookies

During my studies, I had to create a backend on ASP.NET Core for the finished front. But I got stuck during the authentication implementation. The problem is that `signInManager.IsSignedIn(User)` and `User.IsAuthorized` is always false. I didn't find anything on the internet.

Login:

```
[HttpPost("/confirm/login")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromForm] UserLoginningModel userModel, [FromServices] UserManagerServiceBase userManager)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var result = await   userManager.LoginUserAsync(_mapper.Map<UserForLoginningDto>(userModel));

        if (result.Success)
        {
            return Redirect("/");
        }

        foreach (var error in result.Errors)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", error);
        }
    }

    return View(userModel);
}
```

Method `userManager.LoginUserAsync()` is custom method:

```
public override async Task<AuthenticationResult> LoginUserAsync(UserForLoginningDto userDto)
{
    var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(userDto.UserName, userDto.Password, true, lockoutOnFailure: true);

    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
        return AuthenticationResult.SuccessResult;
    }

    if (result.IsLockedOut)
    {
        return new AuthenticationResult("This account is locked out");
    }
    else
    {
        return new AuthenticationResult("Invalid password or email");
    }
}
```

Services:

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);

        options.LoginPath = new PathString("/login");
        options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Errors?status=404");
        options.SlidingExpiration = true;
    });

[...]

services.AddControllersWithViews();
```

Application:

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}");
});
```

When I click Login on the login page `_signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync()` returns Succeed. But `signInManager.IsSignedIn(User)` on index page returns false. I have no idea what's going on.

Cookies AspNetCore.Cookies isn't present too

Answer (score 1):

I change `services.AddDefaultIdentity()` part to this:

```
services.AddIdentityCore<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<LoveFitIdentityDbContext>()
    .AddSignInManager()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

And `services.AddAuthentication()` part to this:

```
services.AddAuthentication(o =>
{
    o.DefaultScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
    o.DefaultSignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
})
    .AddIdentityCookies(o =>
    {
        o.ApplicationCookie?.Configure(options =>
        {
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
            options.LoginPath = new PathString("/login");

            options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Errors?status=404");
            options.SlidingExpiration = true;
        });
    });
```

And it worked